# idiomatic way to perform unique task using akka cluster

Tags: scala, akka

I am starting to use AKKA cluster.  I would like that a certain task will be performed by a single actor. If that actor is down, it should be performed by other actor. I thought doing that by tracking the LeaderChanged event and check if the current Actor is the leader. Something like

```
case LeaderChanged => 
if ((cluster.state.leader.map(_ == cluster.selfAddress).getOrElse(false))
 //do some task
```

is that the idiomatic way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do that is by using cluster singleton http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.1/scala/cluster-singleton.html